# Android-Bootstrap mvn clean package error

Tags: android, dagger

I'm trying to use the android bootstrap : https://github.com/donnfelker/android-bootstrap.

I clone the code.but when 
So i try the next command from the app directory :

```
mvn clean package
```

but get Something wrong.

```
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project android-bootstrap: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] \Users\keepcleargas\android-bootstrap\app\src\main\java\com\donnfelker\android\bootstrap\BootstrapModule.java:[33,8] Error: can not find symbol
[ERROR] \Users\keepcleargas\android-bootstrap\app\src\main\java\com\donnfelker\android\bootstrap\BootstrapModule.java:[33,22] The error: <none> initialization procedure is illegal.
```

can't recognize the symbol 'entryPoints'.

```
@Module
(
        complete = false,

        entryPoints= {
                BootstrapApplication.class,
                BootstrapAuthenticatorActivity.class,
                CarouselActivity.class,
                BootstrapTimerActivity.class,
                CheckInsListFragment.class,
                NewsActivity.class,
                NewsListFragment.class,
                UserActivity.class,
                UserListFragment.class,
                TimerService.class
        }

)
```

Comment: the question solved by https://github.com/donnfelker/android-bootstrap/issues/44.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symbol `entryPoints` has been renamed to to `injects`.

See discussion here: https://github.com/donnfelker/android-bootstrap/issues/44